# How to call service methods in ngCordova plugin success callback?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a function in a service that uses `$cordovaFileTransfer`.

Within the successc callback of this plugin, how do I call other methods of this service, or how to manipulate variables in this service?

Below in the service that I am using:

```
.factory("videoService", function($http, $cordovaCapture, $ionicPlatform, $cordovaFileTransfer, $q, $localstorage, SERVER, USER, UTILS){

  var obj = {

    // videos list
    video_data : {},

    // intermediate temp object to store currently being uploaded video data
    temp_video_data : {},

    // launches camera, uploads video to server on save
    captureVideo : function(){

      var defer = $q.defer();

      // set videCapture options
      var videoCapture_options = { limit: 1, duration: 5 };       

      // set upload meta-data
      var user_data = USER.getUserDetails();
      var d = String(new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10));
      var file_name = "yoro:" + String(user_data["username"]) + ":" + d + ".mp4";

      user_data["date"] = d;      
      user_data["file_name"] = file_name;

      console.log("user_data - >");
      console.log(user_data);

      // launch camera, saving and uploading done in success callback
      $cordovaCapture.captureVideo(videoCapture_options)
      .then(function(videoData) {

        // get local filesystem path of captured video 
        var url = videoData[0].fullPath;
        obj.temp_video_data["url"] = url;

        // initiate video uploading to server
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', function(){
          // set options for uploading
          var trustAllHosts = true;
          var options_ft = {
            fileKey: "yoro_vid",
            fileName: file_name,
            chunkedMode: false,
            mimeType: "video/mp4",
            params: user_data,
          };

          $cordovaFileTransfer.upload(SERVER.upload_video, url, options_ft, trustAllHosts)
            .then(
            // success callback
            function(result, USER) {
              console.log("cordovaFileTransfer returned in service ->");
              console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
              if (result.responseCode===200){
                var data = result.response;
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                // update can_upload flag 
                //USER.can_upload_flag = result.response.can_upload;

                // fetch guid and (pythonic)created_at of uploaded video
                var video_data = result.response.video_data; 
                console.log(JSON.stringify(video_data));
                //video_data["local_path"] = videoService.temp_video_data["url"];

                // store video information in service object
                //obj.video_data.push(video_data);

                // store information in localstorage
                setVideoDataLocalStorage(video_data);

                defer.resolve(true);
              }

            }, 
            // error callback
            function(err) {
              defer.resolve(false);
            }, 
            // progress
            function (progress) {
              //alert(progress);
            }
            );

        }, false);

      });

      return defer.promise;
    },


    // gets video history : gets all videos' guids and created_at(s)
    getVideosHistory : function(){

      var defer = $q.defer();
      var post_data = {
        "username" : USER.user_data["username"],
        "passkey" : USER.user_data["passkey"],
        "guid" : USER.user_data["guid"],
      };

      $http.post(SERVER.get_user_history, post_data)
      .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
        if (status===200){
          var number = parseInt(data["videos_number"]);
          console.log("Video data obtained -> " + String(number));
          console.log(data);
          if(number===0){
            defer.resolve("empty");
          }
          else{
            obj.video_data = data["videos"];
            defer.resolve(true);
          } 
        }
      })
      .error(function(data, status, headers, config){
        console.log("Error in getting video history.")
        defer.resolve(false);
      });

      return defer.promise;
    },

    // video data in local storage is a list of dictionaries corresponding to a video
    setVideoDataLocalStorage : function(video_data){
      console.log("in setVideoDataLocalStorage");
      for (var k in video_data)
        var vid_guid = k;
      var local_storage_video_data = $localstorage.getObject("video_data");
      local_storage_video_data.push({var_guid : video_data});
      console.log("out setVideoDataLocalStorage");
      console.log(JSON.stringify($localstorage.getObject("video_data")));
    },

  }; // end of obj

  return obj;

})
```

I want to call the `setVideoDataLocalStorage` method in the success callback.

Beginner here, please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you can do it but I find it easiest to declare the service object up top as a local variable. Then, rather than define all the methods inside the object itself, I just pass in references to function declarations made underneath. You can then easily access any of the methods or properties on your service anywhere else in your service.

```
app.factory('videoService', function($http, $cordovaCapture, $ionicPlatform, $cordovaFileTransfer, $q, $localstorage, SERVER, USER, UTILS){

    // declare or service object as a local variable
    // so we can easily access it's properties 
    // if we need to elsewhere in the service
    var videoService = {
        videoData                   : {},
        tempVideoData               : 'foo',
        captureVideo                : captureVideo,
        getVideosHistory            : getVideosHistory,
        setVideoDataLocalStorage    : setVideoDataLocalStorage
    };

    // return our service..

    return videoService;
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // implement our service methods...

    function captureVideo(){
     // ...

        $cordovaFileTransfer
            .upload(/* args ... */)
            .then(function(){

                // can easily access other methods on our videoService
                videoService.setVideoDataLocalStorage();

            });
    }

    function getVideosHistory(){
        // ..implement function here
    }

    function setVideoDataLocalStorage(videoData){
        // ..implement function here
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I organised my code in the manner you said and it worked like a charm!

I shall stick to this convention in future!